# How to access files on USB stick from FreeDOS?

Tags: freedos, unetbootin

I made a FreeDOS bootable USB stick with Unetbootin and then put some files in the root directory. When I booted it in Livecd mode, The files were not in the root directory or any subdirectories. How do I access them?

Answer (score 1):

FreeDos does not provide any USB support on it's own.
Just like back in the "godd ol' DOS days", you will need a driver.

Fortunately for you, you might find a driver for that purpose [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/usbdos.html).

There are some caveats however.. here is a snippet from the driver package:

> The main limitation is that the only USB Host Controller protocol
> included here is UHCI (Universal Host Controller Interface).  This
> means that these programs will currently only work with USB host
> controllers manufactured by Intel Corporation or Via Technologies

Even if your controller doesn't meet this specification, I would at least *try* it anyways as you have nothing to lose.

I can't tell you how to get it working as I am not going to read the docs for you but hopefully this will help you out.